# Effect of spatial autocorrelation in explanatory variable of ordinary least squares regression

Tags: least-squares, autocorrelation, spatial, predictor

I am performing ordinary least squares regression analysis on two variables: K concentration in soil as explanatory variable, and thickness of stalk of plants as the other. The K-concentration dataset shows significant spatial autocorrelation (p <0.01).  The results return a very low R2, but the residuals are not spatially autocorrelated. The F-Statistic indicates that the model is not significant.
Could the spatial autocorrelation (clustering) in the input variable be hampering the functionality of this model?

I have posted this on the GIS stackexchange as well.

Comment: Are your variables defined on a 2D grid? Or point samples? If there is any pre-processing to estimate co-located versions of the two variables, then this could have significant impact.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Decide where you want your question & delete the other. You can also ask a statistical question here, & a *related* (but not identical) question on GIS (eg, using ArcGIS software for this).

Comment: The variables are defined on a 2D grid; the two variables are co-located.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, gung; I have changed my question on the GIS forum.